# How to have a selected state that overrides jQuery hover?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of links that change the different content of an information box with javascript.

I am using jquery hover on the links for a mouseover effect:

```
$('a.year').hover(
function (event) {
    console.log("mouseover detected");  
        $(this).animate({   fontSize: '16px',
                            color: '#405481',
                            opacity: '1'
                        },  100);
    },
function (event) {
        $(this).animate({   fontSize: '10px',
                            color: '#405481',
                            opacity: '0.25'
                        },  100);
    }
);
```

and I'm also trying to create a selected state by switching the class so the current link stays larger without the hover function still effecting it:

```
$("#" + value).toggleClass('year year_selected');
```

the problem is that the class switch doesnt work! any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a.year').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        if (!$(this).is('.year_selected')) {
            $(this).animate({   fontSize: '16px',
                                color: '#405481',
                                opacity: '1'
                            },  100);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).animate({   fontSize: '10px',
                            color: '#405481',
                            opacity: '0.25'
                        },  100);
    },
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //depending on markup to find selector, I'm assuming siblings
        $(this).addClass('.year_selected').siblings().removeClass('.year_selected');

    }
});
```

Comment: hi there thanks for your reply, for some reason this resets all the dynamically positioned links and no hover or javascript href works anymore?

Comment: there is an unexpected identifier in the 4th line of this? hmmm

Comment: hi thanks for your reply! the hover is now working, but the addClass year_selected bit isn't though :/

Comment: It's just an example, I've used siblings to remove the class on sibling elements, if the other elements are'nt siblings, that wont work, but I have no idea what your markup looks like ?

Comment: yes siblings is correct however when i inspect it, the class is becoming "year .year_selected" rather than "year_selected" - maybe its to do with 'addClass'? the solution must be close! i'll have a look at alternative class adding things?

Comment: hi i found a solution! it involves the same if statement during mouseleave and direct css manipulation on the siblings to ensure the browser reacts when it is clicked. thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude the link(s) with your `.year_selected` class using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/);

`$('a.year').not('.year_selected').hover( ... );`